# Counting Characters in python grok

Tags: python, grok

there is a task where i have to enter names and at the end print how many different characters and how many repeats.

'Your program should read in multiple lines of input, until a blank line is entered. Then it should print out how many unique characters were named, and how many were repeated.'

This was my result:

Character: The doctor
Character: Rose
Character: Rory
Character: Clara
Character: K-9
Character: The Master
Character: The Doctor
Character: Amy
Character:
You named 8 character(s)
You repeated 1 time(s)

This was my code:

```
count = []   
country = input('Character: ')
a = country.count(country)
b = 0
c = 0
while country:
 count.append(country)
  country = input('Character: ')
  if a == country:
    b = b + 1
  else:
    c = c + 1
c = c - b
count.sort()
print('You named',c,'character(s)')
print('You repeated',a,'time(s)')
```

Supposed to say:

Character: The Doctor
Character: Rose
Character: Rory
Character: Clara
Character: K-9
Character: The Master
Character: The Doctor
Character: Amy
Character:
You named 7 character(s).
You repeated 1 time(s).

Comment: I'd recommend using a set https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Note that this is essentially homework, and https://groklearning.com/ provides online tutor assistance within the system to help you figure it out for yourself, so you should really ask there rather than getting a solution here and learning little.

Comment: @beldaz i figured it out another way and had already submitted it but i didn't understand it so on this website i submitted as much as i understood, i just use this to help understand.

Comment: Good for you for trying to understand things better. Hope you're learning lots from the Challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
country = input('Character: ')

a = country.count(country)
b = 0
c = 0

while country:

 count.append(country)
 country = input('Character: ')
 if country in count:
   b = b + 1
 else:
   c = c + 1

count.sort()
print('You named',c,'character(s)')
print('You repeated',b,'time(s)')
```

Result:

> Character: "AA"
>   Character: "BB"
>   Character: "CC"
>   Character: "BB"
>   Character: ""
>   ('You named', 3, 'character(s)')
>   ('You repeated', 1, 'time(s)')

Key changes:

```
 if country in count:     //changed
```

---

```
   c = c - b             //removed
```

---

```
print('You named',c,'character(s)')        //changed
print('You repeated',b,'time(s)')          //changed
```

Comment: ended up solving it without fully understanding, thanks for posting this as now i know how it works and it is much simpler thanks to you!

Comment: uh... no problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You can gather up the characters and their occurrence counts into a dict. (There's also `collections.Counter()` which is geared for this, but for simplicity, but a regular dict will do.)

```py
character_counts = {}

while True:
    character = input("Character: ")
    if not character:  # Empty line?
        break  # Quit the loop
    # Get the current count for the character, or 0 if not found, increment with one,
    # assign back to the dict.
    character_counts[character] = character_counts.get(character, 0) + 1

# Get a list of characters who occur more than once.
repeated_characters = [
    character
    for (character, count) in character_counts.items()
    if count > 1
]

print("You named {} character(s)".format(len(character_counts)))
print("You repeated {} time(s)".format(len(repeated_characters)))
```

Answer (score -1):

The following snippet can be used:

```
n<-ncol(data)

m<-mean(rowMeans(data))

exp_val<-mean(apply(data,1,var))

v<-var(rowMeans(data))-mean(apply(data,1,var))/n

z<-n/(n+exp_val/v)

premiums<-Z*rowMeans(data)+(1-z)*m
```